# How to dynamically insert and remove rows

Tags: gtk3, vala

I'm looking for a widget which can be dynamically resized. I need to append and remove rows.
There are a methods coming with Grid, like **gtk_grid_insert_row** or **gtk_grid_insert_next_to**, but I don't find any **xxx_remove_xxx** method.

I'm developing a simple http client (to test an api). And I'm adding the possibility to append and remove "GET" variables dynamically.

The UI is made with rows containing a combobox (for variable selection), an entry (for its value) and on the last row a remove button.

Every time I set a variable, a new line (new available variable) is appended.
And every time I unset a variable, the corresponding line is removed.

[image]

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Gtk.Grid doesn't have a remove method; but Gtk.Container does.  Since Grid is a Container, you can use gtk_container_remove.

The docs for this are here:
[GTK+ 3 Reference Manual: GtkContainer : gtk-container-remove](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/3.8/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-remove)

Comment: thx for the answer, but gtk_container_remove removes a GtkWidget, and it is an entire grid row I need to remove. Every time I add a new line, I have to call insert_row to be sure there is enough row in the grid. And I'm not sure that if a row is empty it will be deleted.

Comment: In this case, maybe it's better to write a "row widget" and pack multiple of those into a HBox? This way you can remove/add using just one pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the widget you are looking for is [Gtk.ListBox](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListBox.html). It's a container so you can [add](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-add) and [remove](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-remove) rows easily.

Comment: I made a widget extending a Gtk.Box (representing the line) into a vertical Gtk.Box, it works. Gtk.ListBox seems great but I'm using gtk3.8 (3.9 needed for ListBox), in a future update. thx.

Comment: Your links are dead.

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer I have just fixed that :) Now they should work!